# Javascript API - calling nokia.maps.map.Display with zoomLevel causes map container div to fill entire page

Tags: javascript, here-api

If I remove the ", zoomLevel: 10" part, then I can see the "Hello World" div.  If I add it back in, then the mapContainer div takes over the entire page, so that I cannot see the "Hello World" div.  Can you point me to an example of how I should code my html/css/javascript to control how much of the page the map element takes over?

```
<div>Hello World</div>
<div id="mapContainer"></div>
~
~
~
var map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(mapContainer, {
    center: [52.51, 13.4], zoomLevel: 10 

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some sort of combination of either:

- percentages with position absolute such as `width:100%; height:90%; left: 0;
  top: 1em; position: absolute;`
- fixed pixel size on the height e.g. `width:600px; height:600px;`

In other words something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7; IE=EmulateIE9" />



<title>Map with a DIV</title>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

<script language="javascript"  src="http://api.maps.nokia.com/2.2.4/jsl.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div> I'm a DIV</div>
<div id="mapcanvas"  style="width:100%; height:600px;" >&nbsp;</div><br/><br/>  


<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[    

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Don't forget to set your API credentials
//
// Replace with your appId and token which you can obtain when you 
// register on http://api.developer.nokia.com/ 
//
            nokia.Settings.set( "appId", "YOUR APP ID GOES HERE"); 
            nokia.Settings.set( "authenticationToken", "YOUR AUTHENTICATION TOKEN GOES HERE");

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   


 map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(document.getElementById('mapcanvas'), {
     'components': [ 
        // Behavior collection
        new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior(), 
        new nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomBar()
        ],
    'zoomLevel': 5, // Zoom level for the map
    'center': [41.0125,28.975833] // Center coordinates
});
// ]]>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```